# How to use factory method in component?

Tags: angular

I have the factory method:

```
const documentCustomBlockFactory = (httpClient: HttpClient, model: CustomBlockModel): DocumentCustomBlock => {
        try {
            switch (model.type) {
                case 'doc_num_date_block':
                    return new DocNumDateBlock(httpClient, model);

                default:
                    throw new Error('Undefined block type!');
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + e);
        }
}
```

As you can see it depends on two parameters: `httpClient: HttpClient, model: CustomBlockModel`.
I need to use this factory in component and pass `model` like this:

```
export class DialogLoadDocumentComponent {
    constructor(
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { type: string }) {
             documentCustomBlockFactory(httpClient, data.model);
     }
}
```

So, I need to call a factory based dinamic parameter `public data: { type: string }` that comes to component

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but I suppose you can use the `providers` array from the dialog component decorator:

```
@Component({
  providers: [{ 
    provide: CustomBlockModel,
    useFactory: documentCustomBlockFactory,
    deps: [ HttpClient, MAT_DIALOG_DATA ]
  }]
})
export class DialogLoadDocumentComponent {
  constructor(private block: CustomBlockModel) {}
}
```

This is under a couple assumptions. The `CustomBlockModel` is either a class with the `@Injectable` or an interface declared as an `InjectionToken`, and the `DocNumDateBlock` extends the `CustomBlockModel`.